# Java Regular expression matching square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do the following using regular expression (java replaceAll):

```
**Input:**
Test[Test1][Test2]Test3

**Output**
TestTest3
```

In short, i need to remove everything inside square brackets including square brackets.

I'm trying this, but it doesn't work:

```
\\[(.*?)\\]
```

Would you be able to help?

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: VTC, lacks MCVE where the pattern fails. http://ideone.com/wf5YMT

Comment: Do you plan to have _nested_ brackets, or would everything be top level as you have shown here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Everything top level. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
\[[^\[]*\]
```

and replace by empty

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fVTQjy/4/)

Sample Java Source:

```
final String regex = "\\[[^\\[]*\\]";
final String string = "Test[Test1][Test2]Test3\n";
final String subst = "";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Thanks @Rizwan, it works, +1 for the sample source even though you did not need to take the pain!

Comment: @sash glad to know that it worked for you and never mind the pain! as long as the source is a generated one :) you can also generate from regex101.com

Answer (score 3):

Your original pattern works for me:

```
String input = "Test[Test1][Test2]Test3";
input = input.replaceAll("\\[.*?\\]", "");
System.out.println(input);
```

**Output:**

```
TestTest3
```

Note that you don't need the parentheses inside the brackets.  You would use that if you planned to capture the contents in between each pair of brackets, which in your case you don't need.  It isn't wrong to have them in there, just not necessary.

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Thanks Tim. +1 for you .This works but @Rizwan was fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[\w+]
```

This works for me, this regex matches all the words which are enclosed in square brackets.