# Regular expression for replacing "[" "]" with single quote " ' " character in string

Tags: regex

Hi I am new to regular expression. 
I have string like this

`"( NATIVE_WHERE_CLAUSE =  'UnitOfMeasure.MeasurementType=[Weight]'  ) AND ( NATIVE_RELATION_WHERE_CLAUSE =  'Reference_Name=[Nut to coolent oil]'  )"`

I tried replace the square brackets `[]` with single quote `'` with `replaceAll()` method. But it did not work.

Can any one help me what will be regular expression for replacing the square brackets `[]` with single quote in my above string.

Comment: That expression will create a double ' in the string: `...Type='Weight'' ) AND ...`. Are you sure you want to do that? You probably want something like `#[\[\]]/\\'#` (`:%s/[\[\]]/\\'/g` if you do that with `sed` or inside `vim`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Regular expression matching square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43246115/java-regular-expression-matching-square-brackets)

Answer (score 0):

`\\[\\]` replace `[]` in a string. And use below to replace `[]` with `'`

```
"( NATIVE_WHERE_CLAUSE =  'UnitOfMeasure.MeasurementType=[Weight]'  ) AND ( NATIVE_RELATION_WHERE_CLAUSE =  'Reference_Name=[Nut to coolent oil]'  )".replace(new RegExp('\\[|\\]', 'g'), "'");
```

but that creates two single quotes, one as a child of other. That will not work. So, you must replace with `\'` to avoid the error as shown below.

```
"( NATIVE_WHERE_CLAUSE =  'UnitOfMeasure.MeasurementType=[Weight]'  ) AND ( NATIVE_RELATION_WHERE_CLAUSE =  'Reference_Name=[Nut to coolent oil]'  )".replace(new RegExp('\\[|\\]', 'g'), "\\'");
```